# C++ Reading/writing long values to binary file

Tags: c++, fstream

I am trying to read and write an array of longs to a binary file using fstream. I have the arrays defined as following:

```
#define MAX_SUB_BUCKETS 27    
unsigned long origin[MAX_SUB_BUCKETS];
unsigned long nextAvail[MAX_SUB_BUCKETS];
fstream fh;
```

I open the file and try the following:

```
fh.open(fileName.c_str(), fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::binary);
if (fh.fail()) {
         // create new file here and write all zeroes to it (plus header)
} else {
          fh.seekg (0, ios::beg);
          for (i=0;i<MAX_SUB_BUCKETS;i++) {
                     fh.read(origin[i],sizeof(long));               
          }
          for (i=0;i<MAX_SUB_BUCKETS;i++) {
                     fh.read (nextAvail[i],sizeof(long));
          }
}
```

The compiler complains with the following errors:

```
tld.hh:39: error: invalid conversion from 'long unsigned int' to 'char*'
tld.hh:39: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::read(_CharT*, std::streamsize) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]'
tld.hh:42: error: invalid conversion from 'long unsigned int' to 'char*'
tld.hh:42: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::read(_CharT*, std::streamsize) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]'
tld.hh:45: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'char*'
tld.hh:45: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::read(_CharT*, std::streamsize) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]'
```

Where line 39 is the first fh.read() call. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here (except for my basic lack of knowledge about these things). I'm also sure there is probably a way to read the entire array of origin or nextAvail in a single statement rather than a loop.

Comment: The declaration of `fh`, or at least its type, would be important here...

Comment: If you have even the remotest whims of making this reasonably portable, consider using `htonl()` and `ntohl()` once you get this squared away, btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error, it looks like you are trying to do a `read` with `unsigned long`s on a *stream* that operats on `char`s. You can try with something like this:

```
fh.read( reinterpret_cast< char* >( &origin[i] ), sizeof( long ) );
```

Comment: That did the trick (at least as far as getting rid of the compiler errors). Now let's see if I can make it work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since binary files are arrays of bytes, you need to write some routine that converts the data you want to store in the file into an array of bytes in some particular format. To read them back, you need to write a routine that reads an array of bytes from a file and converts them into whatever form you would like them to be in.

Essentially, you need to write serialization (structured data to a bunch of bytes) and deserialization (bunches of bytes to structured data) routines. You may wish to use a format like XML or JSON (or even raw text) because they're very easy to understand and libraries to convert to and from these formats are widely available.